# Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. I'm not sure which code causes the conflict

Tags: ios, swift

I have two views. and they were created in storyboard and have outlet variables. (topView and bottomSecondview) When I turn on switchState, I'd like secondBottomView to show up and when I turn on switchstate2, I'd like topView to show up. it works well until I turn on the both switches. once I turn on the both switches (which means the both views have to show up), I see this in console: Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints. I'm not sure where there's the conflict. Please help me.

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey:"switchState") == true && UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState2") == false {
         topView.isHidden = true
        secondBottomView.isHidden = false
             secondBottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
             secondBottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myUIProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myUIProgressView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomView.topAnchor, constant: -11).isActive = true
             secondBottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myUIProgressView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true          
    }

    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState2")  == true && UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState") == false {
            secondBottomView.isHidden = true
           topView.isHidden = false
         topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
         topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myUIProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 111).isActive = true
         topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.topAnchor , constant: -11).isActive = true
         topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myUIProgressView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
         topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myUIProgressView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                   }

if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState") == true && UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "switchState2") == true {
        topView.isHidden = false
        topView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        topView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myUIProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        topView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.topAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        topView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        topView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        topView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        topView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: secondBottomView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true

        secondBottomView.isHidden = false
        secondBottomView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        secondBottomView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomView.topAnchor, constant:-10).isActive = true
        secondBottomView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
        secondBottomView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
        secondBottomView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
        secondBottomView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topView.heightAnchor, multiplier: 1).isActive = true
      secondBottomView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.myUIProgressView.bottomAnchor, constant: 11).isActive = false       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `topView` and `secondBottomView` has the `topAnchor` set to the `bottomAnchor` of `progressView`. Remove the `topAnchor` constraint on `secondBottomView`.

There seems to be quite a few problems with your constraints. It's easier for you to achieve something similar using `UIStackView` with auto layout. Add a new `UIStackView` with vertical axis under your `progressView`. Add both `topView` and `secondBottomView` to the `UIStackView`. On changing the switch states, simple show or hide the `topView` or `secondBottomView` as

```
topView.isHidden = true; // Hides topView
secondBottomView.isHidden = true; // Hides secondBottomView
```

This way, using `UIStackView`, you wouldn't have to take care of all those constraints.

Comment: thank you for your answer. it's set as false. and I removed it from the code.. I still have the same situation.

Comment: The width and height anchors of topView and secondBottomView are circularly dependent on each other. Set it to self.view.widthAnchor and self.view.heightAnchor in both the cases.

Comment: I still have the same case. "the 3rd if clause" works well if I turn on the both switches and then turn off the simulator and then turn it on again, which I guess means "the 3rd if clause" itself doesn't have problem. but once I turn on the first switch or the second switch from the both switches on, it causes the conflict.

Comment: ah, I see! thank you once again. by the way, could this be a reason? all the codes are in override fun viewWillAppear(_ animated:Bool) { here the codes are } when this method is called, they don't work well but when I approach from tableview, the code works well.

Comment: Most operations related to views must be done in the viewDidLoad method. This method is called only once, when the views are loaded into memory. But viewWillAppear can be called multiple times during the lifecycle of an app, and there is no point in recreating the same constraints for these views again and again.